# JS how to delete / deactivate / destroy all methods, classes, setTimouts and setIntervals in one fell swoop?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that creates animation. It includes calls to other classes, methods of other classes, setTimeouts, etc. My task is to make the exit button from this animation. By clicking on this button, all these classes, methods, loops should stop working. What is the best way to do this?

```
// build html for animation
class BuildPhone{
  constructor(idElement) {
    this.create(idElement)
  }
  create(idElement) {
    this.createWrap(idElement)
    this.createDisplay()
    this.createElements()
  }
  createWrap(idElement){
    document.querySelector('idElement')
    // set wrapper for phone
  }
  createDisplay(){
    // set display iphone
  }
  createElements(){
    // set time in display, wi-fi, battery, btn's Home,Back,Apps
  }
}

// run chating animation
class Chat{
  constructor(messages){
    this.messages = messages
    this.startChating()
  }
  async startChating(){
    const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    
    var timerFunc = function(i) {
      return async function() {
        await timeout(3000); // 3 sek delay before send new message

        this.sendMessage(this.messages[i])
        this.scrollToBottom()

        if (i < this.messages.length) {
          setTimeout(timerFunc(++i), 0); 
        }
      }
    }
    setTimeout(timerFunc(0), 500); // start loop
  }
  sendMessage(message){
    // add message text to list messages in chat
  }
  scrollToBottom(){
    // this code for scrolling to bottom in chat after send message
  }
}

class PhoneAnimation{
  constructor(args) {
    create(args)
  }
  async create(args) {
    // build html for animation
    await new BuildPhone(args.idElement)
    // run chating animation
    await new Chat(args.messages)
  }

}

// ------ init -------
args = {
  idElement: '#targetElement1',
  messages: [
    {
      from: 'app',
      text: 'hello)'
    },
    {
      from: 'user',
      text: 'hi'
    },
    {
      from: 'app',
      text: 'how are you?'
    },
  ]
}

// init animation
new PhoneAnimation(args)
//HOW TO KILL ALL ANIMATION IF IT RUNED?
```

result - need stoped classes, async methods and functions, setTimouts and setIntervals through some mechanism

Comment: `window.reload()`

Comment: Half joking, but seriously, that's asking to do alot of stuff with a single button click.

Comment: Please show an simplified example of the code.

Comment: Add a `stop()` method to all your classes, and maintain a list of all the objects that need to be stopped when the user clicks the exit button. Then you can loop over the list calling all the stop methods.

Comment: @Taplar Bad suggestion, why bring a bazooka to hammer a nail.

Comment: Have everything sharing the same [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)?

Comment: In all seriousness, unless you are tracking every one of those things that you mentioned, the answer is no. Maybe create a Web Worker and do everything in that, but destroying that worker would be equivalent to reload.

Comment: Please don't link to external code hosting sites.  Add your code ***here***, not elsewhere.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin ok. I added link on example.

Comment: @zero298 ok) one moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function returns a handler that you can use to stop de timer.

```
var timer;

function tick() {
   // do stuff
   timer = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
}

function stop () {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = undefined;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** the next part is only a rough example (I have not made it possible to restart. It would be easy to extend it.)

```
var timerHub = {
   "timers":{}
  ,"setTimeout": function (groupName, fn, time) {
                   groupName = groupName || "@";
                   var timer = setTimeout(fn ,time);
                   if (! timers.hasOwnProperty(groupName)) { 
                     timers[groupName] = {"isStopped":false,"list":[]};
                   }
                   timers[groupName].list.push(timer);
                 }
  ,"isStopped": function (groupName) {
                   groupName = groupName || "@";
                   if (! timers.hasOwnProperty(groupName)) { 
                     return true;
                   }
                   return timers[groupName].isStopped; 
                 }
  ,"stop": function (groupName) {
                   groupName = groupName || "@";
                   if (! timers.hasOwnProperty(groupName)) { 
                     return;
                   }
                   timers[groupName].isStopped = true; 
                   timers[groupName].list.map((t) => {
                     if (!t) return t;
                     clearTimeout(t);
                     return undefined;
                   });
                 }
};
```

Comment: yes, but this only for seTimout. 
there are a lot of these things in my project and they intersect with cycles. I’m wondering how I can best make it so that I can stop all loops, timeouts, deactivate classes from one place (taking into account that there are await everywhere)

Comment: Create an object where you centralize all timeouts with a group name associated with them.  When you want to stop a group of timeout you do something like `obj.stop(groupName);`.  And at the begining of the async callback you add something like `if (obj.isStopped(groupName)) return;`.

Comment: @DimiSoso I've added an example of what it would look like.  You have to replace the `setTimeout(resolve, ms)` by `timerHub.setTimeout('something', resolve, ms)`.